# how to use javascript to embed flash into ios

Tags: javascript, flash

I wonder how can i run web flash application on IOS?

Because i heard some information about Flash application can run on IOs using Javascript

But i dont know how to write javascript code to make flash run on IOs

Do you have any tutorial or resources to help me to do this ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for > http://www.guidingtech.com/mobiles/how-to-play-flash-videos-on-your-iphone-or-ipod-touch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a number of attempts to get Flash onto iOS devices ([converting Flash apps to iOS apps](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html), or [recreating the runtime in JavaScript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/gordon-flash-runtime-implemented-in-javascript)) but I doubt any of the solutions would be suitable.

You’d be better off building your application in HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not support Flash on its iOS devices. Apple and Adobe had quite a nasty [bust-up](http://www.itworld.com/software/95437/adobe-apple-spar-over-flash-ipad-mac) over this issue. And, to make matters worse, it doesn't look like its going to improve any time soon (see [here](http://www.itworld.com/legal/104320/adobe-vs-apple-going-get-uglier)). So the only thing you can do is use HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript to develop your web apps for iOS.